# Updating a single field using `UPDATE table SET field = ? WHERE key = ?;` fails with `table.another_field may not be NULL`

Tags: sqlite, perl

(I'm writing my first Perl DBI program using SQLite)

When trying to update a single field in a record executing the prepared statement

> UPDATE *table* SET *field* = ? WHERE *key* = ?;

I get an error saying

> *table*.*another_field* may not be NULL

It is true that *another_field* has a `NOT NULL` restriction, but the record to update has the data filled in already.

Is it a misconception that I can `UPDATE` a record specifying only the field to set using

> SET *field* = *value*

Naturally when just wanting to update a single field it seems a kind of overkill to read the existing record using `SELECT` just to set all those values that aren't to be changed, just because they may not be `NULL`.

I'm using SQLite 3.93.3 and Perl 5.18.2 on Linux x86_64.

## Details

(Originally I thought those details are not important for the problem, but maybe they are, so here are some, also answering questions from the comments.

### Table Definition

The table's name is `KEYS`, the *field*'s name is `KEYDATA`, and the *other_field* is `KEK_DATA`.

```sqlite
CREATE TABLE KEYS (
ID              INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT       NOT NULL,
NAME            VARCHAR(30)                             NOT NULL,
DK_DATA         VARCHAR(128)                            NOT NULL,
KEK_DATA        VARCHAR(128)                            NOT NULL,
KEYDATA         VARCHAR(4096)                           NOT NULL,
CREATOR         VARCHAR(20),
CREATED         DATETIME,
MODIFIED        DATETIME,
LOCKED          DATETIME);
```

### Triggers

I also have two triggers defined (as I'm a beginner, those triggers may be sub-optimal, but you'll guess what they should do:

```sqlite
CREATE TRIGGER KEY_CREATED AFTER INSERT ON KEYS FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE KEYS SET CREATED = datetime('now') WHERE ID = new.ID;
END;
CREATE TRIGGER KEY_MODIFIED AFTER UPDATE ON KEYS FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE KEYS SET MODIFIED = datetime('now') WHERE ID = new.ID;
END;
```

### SQL Statements

So what's actually triggering the problem is two SQL statements:

1. `SELECT DK_DATA, KEK_DATA FROM KEYS WHERE NAME = ?;`: I need to read those fields to be able to update `KEYDATA`.
2. `UPDATE KEYS SET KEYDATA = ? WHERE NAME = ?;`: The statement that should update the `KEYDATA` field.

### Sample Record

Finally here is a sample record that causes the problem (don't waste your time decoding the data ;-)):

```sqlite
INSERT INTO KEYS VALUES(62,'2','RVYAAQATAhFkdvSkrEyDbbTUnFHfZWEABAExAAUEMTYABAAxAAcDNTA1Nw==','RVYAAQATDWMY2Y1l1PHWU2qrobycBekABAoyABMM04kRSihvavmUHJi4OzhzugAEADEABQsxNg==','RVYAAQAEADEABAcwABMJ5RVnT9DFN0+naro0L6N7Sg==','proc','2023-03-26 00:06:24','2023-03-26 00:06:24',NULL);
```

Note: The final `NAME`s won't be as silly as `2`, but while developing the data model and code it's OK so far.

### Error Message

Here is the original `DBI::errmsg`:
`KEYS.KEK_DATA may not be NULL`

### Checking for `IS NULL`

This is to answer Tim Roberts' question:

```sqlite
sqlite> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM KEYS WHERE KEK_DATA IS NULL;
0
```

Comment: You do not have to set every field in an UPDATE.  Does your table contain rows where `another_field` is already NULL?  That can happen if you alter the table after it has data.

Comment: @TimRoberts No, dumping the database the fields are set; as I wrote: I just want to update a single field in one or more rows.

Comment: Well, what you're saying doesn't make sense.  If you do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE another_field IS NULL;`, is the count non-zero?

Comment: Are there any triggers defined on the table?

Comment: @forpas Yes, I have triggers; If you'd explain why you asked for those, that would have been helpful, too. I'll provide some more information by editing the question in a moment.

Comment: @brian d foy Why did you remove  the `perl` and `dbi` tags? Are you sure this is not a possible bug in Perl's DBI? Why did you remove the `update` tag? Why do you think the question is not related to SQL UPDATE?

Comment: @U.Windl There's no perl or DBI question here. You don't show any Perl code. Also, the update tag isn't that helpful once you have `sqlite` there. If you can do this in sqlite directly but not in Perl, then show us the Perl program you are using. Besides you saying that you are writing a Perl program, there's no content that would make anyone think you are using Perl, and there's no way for a Perl person to answer your question.

Comment: I asked if there are any triggers defined because a trigger may update a column without you trying to update that column explicitly. As it is described your issue it's not something that I can reproduce. Can you reproduce it with sample data in a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vRbqFpk_)? Also, there is no version 3.93.3 of SQLite. Did you mean to write 3.39.3?

Comment: @briandfoy Well, assuming that Perl's DBI basically passes on the SQL statements to SQLite, and SQLite returns an error where @TimRobert say it doesn't make sense, it might be a problem in the PerL's DBI code. However showing the Perl code does not add anything (despite of making the question harder to understand) IMHO. For example the code is very similar to `$stmt = $dbh->prepare(SQL_ADD_KEY); $stmt->bind_param(1, $data, SQL_VARCHAR); $stmt->bind_param(2, $id, SQL_VARCHAR); $stmt->execute();`. However while answering this comment, I found the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the question turned out to be un-answerable with the information provided, and I could delete it as being invalid; however I'll explain what the problem was:

- The problem was not in SQLite
- The problem was not in DBI

Instead the problem was in Perl code, specifically a problem caused by copying similar code and forgetting to adjust it properly:

Instead of preparing

```perl
use constant SQL_PUT_KEY        =>      # update key record
    qq{UPDATE KEYS SET KEYDATA = ? WHERE NAME = ?;};
```

I was preparing

```perl
use constant SQL_ADD_KEY        =>      # insert key record
    qq{INSERT INTO KEYS (NAME, DK_DATA, KEK_DATA, KEYDATA, CREATOR)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);};
```

but still binding the parameters as if `SQL_PUT_KEY` were used.
Thus, as only (the first) two parameters were bound, `KEK_DATA` (and the rest) was `NULL`, actually.
So this should explain the error seen.

Still I wonder when Perl's DBI did not warn about placeholders not being bound when executing the statement; if it did, I would have noticed my mistake even before having to ask here.

Comment: This is why we prefer minimal working examples. There's no way anyone could have answered this. It's still hard to see that the answer actually is because all we see are some SQL templates. We don't see how you use them and how something didn't get bound. Had anyone perused your code and saw that you had 5 placeholders but only 2 values, the answer would have been quick.

Comment: @briandfoy I agree, but sometimes creating minimal working examples is a *huge* amount of work, specifically if you use many helper classes (as I did).

Comment: Creating minimal working examples is very efficient for debugging and solving problems on your own, before even needing to post here. This will actually safe you work.